# Ember.js PushObject not inserting object in an ArrayController

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

I have the following ArrayController:

```
Lead.Controllers.Leads = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  init: ->
    content: Ember.A()

    @view = Ember.View.create
      controller: @
      templateName: 'app/templates/leads/list'

    @view.appendTo $('#leads')

  addLead: (data) ->
    lead = Lead.Lead.create()
    lead.setProperties JSON.parse data
    console.log lead.get 'company'
    debugger
    @pushObject lead
    console.log @get('length')
```

The problem is after I call push object, the length is still `0`. I really cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? The only thing I can think of is that the Content is set to an empty array via `Ember.A()`.

I have no idea what else it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where your problem is since I a) don't really know or use CoffeeScript and b) there's no jsFiddle or working example. But if I'm reading this correctly your trying to do the following: [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/AsRCR/) which works as expected. Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I was not calling _super() from init.  That was the bit I was missing.  It is a pity that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a *Coffee Script* syntax error.
There are two solutions (depending on what you want to implement).

The second example will use the same array for every instance of the controller.
Also, I'd recommend calling `@_super()` when overriding the init method, otherwise you might get some unexpected results with certain classes.

```
Ember.ArrayController.extend
  init: ->
    @_super()
    @set 'content', Ember.A()
    # content

Ember.ArrayController.extend
  content: Ember.A()
  init: ->
    @_super()
    # content
```